# Sort a 2d array php

Tags: php

I have the following $array:

```
$array[1] = (20, 1);
$array[2] = (3, 2);
$array[3] = (25, 3);
$array[4] = (5, 4);
```

I want to sort this array according to the first field and get the result:

```
$sort_array[1] = (3, 2);
$sort_array[2] = (5, 4);
$sort_array[3] = (20, 1);
$sort_array[4] = (25, 3);
```

How do I do that?

Comment: paste your subject line into google  https://www.google.com/search?q=php+sort+2d+array

Comment: If I take the time to post it here, it is because it is not well explained in those links... but thanks for your help

Comment: Well if you don't mention specifics it appears that you haven't put any research effort in which is frowned upon as it is expected people do some research before asking.

Comment: thanks again, very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Use usort for this purpose. For exp:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a["value"] - $b["value"];
}
usort($arr, "cmp");
```